# Create many confusion-like matrices concatenated in python

Tags: python

I have the following pandas dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'cl1': ['A','A','A','A',
                     'A','A','A','A',
                     'D','D','D','D',
                     'D','D','D','D'],
             'cl2': ['C','C','C','C',
                    'B','B','B','B',
                    'C','C','C','C',
                    'B','B','B','B'],
             'p1p2': ['00','01','10','11',
                     '00','01','10','11',
                     '00','01','10','11',
                     '00','01','10','11'],
             'val':[1,2,3,4,
                   10,20,30,40,
                   5,6,7,8,
                   50,60,70,80]})

df

cl1 cl2 p1p2    val
0   A   C   00  1
1   A   C   01  2
2   A   C   10  3
3   A   C   11  4
4   A   B   00  10
5   A   B   01  20
6   A   B   10  30
7   A   B   11  40
8   D   C   00  5
9   D   C   01  6
10  D   C   10  7
11  D   C   11  8
12  D   B   00  50
13  D   B   01  60
14  D   B   10  70
15  D   B   11  80
```

And I would like to create a plot that looks like this

[image]

How could I do that in python ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `p1p2` only contains values 00, 01, 10, or 11, it is easy to use [pivot table](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) to get something like this:

```
d = df.copy()

d['p1'] = d['p1p2'].str[0]
d['p2'] = d['p1p2'].str[1]

counts = d.pivot_table(values = 'val', columns = ['cl1', 'p1'], index = ['cl2', 'p2'])

counts

# cl1      A       D    
# p1       0   1   0   1
# cl2 p2                
# B   0   10  30  50  70
#     1   20  40  60  80
# C   0    1   3   5   7
#     1    2   4   6   8
```

As for the plotting, here's something that is pretty close to what you are looking for:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

colors = pd.pivot_table(d, values = 'p1p2', columns = ['cl1', 'p1'], index = ['cl2', 'p2']).astype(int)
colors = colors.astype(str).applymap(lambda val: int(val, 2))

color_labels = pd.pivot_table(d, values = 'val', columns = ['cl1', 'cl2'], index = ['p1p2']).index

counts.index = counts.index.droplevel(-1)
counts.columns = counts.columns.droplevel(-1)

colors.index = colors.index.droplevel(-1)
colors.columns = colors.columns.droplevel(-1)

cmap = ListedColormap(['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'])
ax = sns.heatmap(colors, cmap = cmap, annot = counts, cbar_kws = {"label": "p1p2 (legend)"})
colorbar = colorbar = ax.collections[0].colorbar
colorbar.set_ticks(np.linspace(0, 3, 9)[1::2])
colorbar.set_ticklabels(color_labels)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're tempted to use the [*Styler*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.html) :

```
d = df.set_index("val")["p1p2"].to_dict()

c = {"00": "#ffff00", "01": "#ffbf00", "10": "#06b050", "11": "#06b0f0"}
 
piv = (
    df.pivot(index=["cl2", "p1p2"], columns="cl1", values="val")
        .droplevel(1).rename_axis(index=None).pipe(
            lambda x: x.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda g:
            pd.DataFrame(
                g.values.reshape(-1, 4),
                columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([list(x), range(2)]))))
        .sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
        .sort_index(level=[0, 1], ascending=[False, True])
)
   
legend = pd.DataFrame(
    df["p1p2"].unique(), index=piv.index,
    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([[""], ["p1p2"]])
)

d = df.set_index("val")["p1p2"].to_dict()
c = {"00": "#ffff00", "01": "#ffbf00", "10": "#06b050", "11": "#06b0f0"}

color = lambda v: f"background-color: {c[d[v]] if v in d else c[v]}"

out = pd.concat([piv, legend], axis=1).style.applymap(color)
```

Output :

[image]